# Quelle est la nuance entre « depuis qu'il a eu 30 ans » et « depuis qu'il a trente ans » ?

Tags: grammaire, indications-de-temps, temps-grammatical

Les phrases suivantes sont issues du livre *Advanced French Grammar* (p. 192) de V Mazet :

> Il ne fume plus depuis qu'il **a eu** trente ans = *He has not smoked since he turned thirty.*

Quelle nuance y a-t-il avec celle-ci ?

> Il ne fume plus depuis qu'il **a** trente ans.

Je m'aperçois que la 1<sup>re</sup> citation emploie le passé composé alors que la 2<sup>e</sup> emploie le présent simple. Mais les deux ne sont-elles pas équivalentes à celle-ci :

> Il ne fume plus depuis l'âge de 30 ans.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Il ne fume plus depuis qu'il a trente ans.

Comme « il a trente ans » est au présent, cette affirmation est toujours vraie. Cette phrase ne peut donc être utilisée qu'entre le 30<sup>e</sup> et le 31<sup>e</sup> anniversaire de la personne en question.

> Il ne fume plus depuis qu'il a eu trente ans.

Cette phrase peut être utilisée à tout moment à partir du 30<sup>e</sup> anniversaire de la personne en question.

« Il a trente ans » peut signifier soit que c'est aujourd'hui le trentième anniversaire de la personne, soit que son âge est compris entre 30 et 31 ans. Dans la première phrase, « il a trente ans » désigne une période (en cours), c'est donc le deuxième sens qui s'applique. Dans la deuxième phrase, « il a eu trente ans » désigne un évènement ponctuel (révolu), c'est donc le premier sens qui s'applique.

> Il ne fume plus depuis l'âge de 30 ans.

Cette phrase est synonyme de la phrase avec « depuis qu'il a eu trente ans ».

Il y a une petite nuance entre la deuxième et la troisième phrase. La deuxième phrase donne l'impression que la personne a arrêté de fumer lors de son 30e anniversaire, ou au moins à une date proche ; la troisième laisse toute l'année possible.

Pour rester plus vague sur la date exacte, j'aurais plutôt tendance à construire la phrase autrement :

> Il a arrêté de fumer vers 30 ans.

Answer (score 0):

Ces deux phrases sont effectivement similaires.

Je dirais cependant que la première laisse sous-entendre qu'*il a décidé d'arrêter de fumer **le jour** de ses trente ans*, alors que la seconde est plus vague, indiquant plutôt qu'*il a arrêté de fumer **l'année** de ses trente ans*.